# "unable to resolve module 'react/lib/React' from '.../react-konva/src/react-konva.js'" error when trying to build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dependencies, react-dom, konvajs

I am somewhat new to React, this being my first project but having spent quite some time learning and writing code in react-native.

I think i have pin-pointed why i am getting the error but i have no idea how to fix it.

What i am trying to do is install and run react-konva, a canvas element library that uses Konva.js to display Canvas elements efficiently in my app. After running `yarn add konva react-konva --save` (already had react) i ran into a dependency issue whereby react-konva requires `react@15.6.1` but other parts of my project require `react@16.0.0-alpha.12`. Thus causing problems. Any insight as to why its happening (if im not right) or how to get around this issue would be amazing.

[This is the Red error screen in the emulator when i have as much as `import { Stage } from 'react-konva';` in my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgADF.png)

[an `npm list --depth=0` of my project to show the dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21A2.png)

The `Package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "amazingProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules\\expo\\AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "konva": "^1.6.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.0",
    "react-konva": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.3",
    "react-native-slider": "0.10.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11",
    "style-equal": "^1.0.0",
    "watchman": "^0.1.8",
    "yarn": "^0.27.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the react-konva already exist in your node modules folder?

Comment: it didnt already exist, in fact i re-made the project and ran yarn to create a fresh `node_modules`.

Comment: i have also tried npm install react konva react-konva --save. Just tried `npm install` instead of `yarn`. then ran `react-native run-android` and it gives me `UnableToResolveError undefined` then the same error as i have screenshotted in the post when i reload which is exactly what it was like before.

Comment: Wait are you developing react-native or react? because from what I see react-konva is for react not react-native?

Comment: Im using react native, if thats really the case then i think i should go back to bed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-konva` doesn't support new react v16 yet.
You can try to use `v15.6.1` of react. Or wait for an update of `react-konva`:

https://github.com/lavrton/react-konva/issues/120

Comment: good to know this but i cant wait for v16 and other parts of my project require v16 of react.